# GIT downloaded dev and branched to feature

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

I have one local dev branch coming from the origin master.
I created a feature branch off of the local dev.

Did some work and pushed the feature *up-stream* back to origin.  It now appears on the server branches.

However, now dev has had changes by other developers... so I did a git pull to my local dev branch, which is now sync-ed up to the server.

Now I need to get those changes into my feature from the local dev before I push feature back up to the origin server.  (OR do I directly merge/pull/whatever from server dev into the feature).

Obviously Im confused.
Thanks in advance for you help/clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If the idea is to update your `feature` branch to catch up with the current state of `dev`, then pull `dev` (you did that), switch to `feature`, and merge `dev` into `feature`.

Alternatively, if you have *not* pushed `feature` yet, you can pull `dev` (you did that), switch to `feature`, and rebase `feature` onto `dev`.

Comment: I'll add that if you have pushed feature but nobody else has done work on it, you can rebase it. We do that since feature branches are almost never shared between devs. As always ask ask ask to make sure.

Comment: Or fetch dev and then merge origin/dev straight into feature. No need to create a local version of dev.

Comment: @jessehouwing Of course I totally agree. The problem is that the OP seems to _already_ have a local `dev`. Otherwise my advice would have been quite differently expressed.

Comment: Maybe better to add a section on, now that you're here as well as a in the future / next time...

Comment: @jessehouwing This is how I teach: I start with where the student actually is. In this case I accept the premise "I created a feature branch off of the local dev" and go from there. Local branches are good for beginners so I see no need to press the matter further.